# Are *all* recursive theories with model $\mathbb{N}$ incomplete?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I'm asking about models in the first order language of arithmetic  $L$ (which has binary operations + and $\cdot$, unary operations < and $S$, and constant 0).

(A version of) Gödel's first incompleteness theorem states that all 'sufficiently strong', recursive, consistent theories in $L$ are incomplete. As I understand, 'sufficiently strong' means that the theory proves arithmetisation of recursive functions; as a result, PA is incomplete.

On the other hand, there is Presburger arithmetic, which is recursive, complete and consistent. I've seen this given as an example of a theory that is not 'sufficently strong' for Gödel incompleteness to hold. However, Presburger arithmetic is only complete with respect to a smaller language; it is *not* complete with respect to $L$ since it proves nothing about the multiplication.

This brings me to my question. I have seen the following argument, which I *think* proves that any recursive theory in $L$ which has the standard naturals $\mathbb{N}$ as a model must be incomplete!

Indeed, let $T$ be such a theory, and let $\varphi(n)$ be a formula with standard interpretation "the $n^\text{th}$ recursive function is total". Let
$$S=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid T\vdash\varphi(n)\}.$$
Since $\mathbb{N}\vDash T$, each element of $S$ is the code for a total recursive function. However, $S$ is recursively enumerable  while the set of all total recursive functions is not. Therefore there is some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\mathbb{N}\vDash\varphi(m)$, yet $T\not\vdash\varphi(m)$. Therefore $T$ is incomplete.

Does this argument work? If so, what is an example of a complete, consistent, recursive theory in $L$? As described above, I don't think Presburger arithmetic fits the bill.

Comment: Yes, this argument works.

Comment: @NoahSchweber do you know of a simple example of a complete, consistent, recursive theory in the language?

Comment: Sure: $$\forall x,y(x=y\wedge x<y).$$

Comment: A simpler way to think about it is that there is only one complete theory with the standard $\mathbb{N}$ as a model (namely, the set of all sentences over $L$ that are true in that model), so you just have to prove that particular complete theory is not recursive.

Comment: Thanks both, this is much clearer to me now :)